# sending messages off pc through phone, with only having app on phone.

Tags: sms

I want to be able to send texts through my laptop, but without having to download anything onto it. Is there any app i can download on my phone to be able to tdo that?

Answer (score 3):

[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) will allow you to do this and more.

[image]

- Transfer files to and from your device via web browser. Wireless
  operation via WiFi connection.
- No client required on computer, enjoy all functions & features just
  in your browser. Free of drivers or computer environment limits.
- IM like interface, search contacts or copy the messages, chat with
  your friends more conveniently. Quick and easy group texting from the
  comfort of your desktop.
- Organize music, photos, videos, messages and call logs with contacts.
  Much easier apps install, uninstall and even backing up. Play music
  and video clips stored on device, or view your photos on the big
  computer screen.
- Provide convenient management on your device. Including Device
  Status, Processes Manager, Apps Manager and SD Card control.
- Device screenshot, multiple desktops, weather, calendar, url
  transfer, etc.

From their site: http://airdroid.com/